# How to remove the first character if it is a specific character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I currently have a table `Telephone` it has entries like the following:

```
9073456789101
+773456789101
0773456789101
```

What I want to do is remove only the 9 from the start of all the entries that have a 9 there but leave the others as they are.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While all other answer are probably also working, I'd suggest to try and use [`STUFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function to easily replace a part of the string.

```
UPDATE Telephone
SET number = STUFF(number,1,1,'')
WHERE number LIKE '9%'
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c2c9/1)**

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code and a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d26ab/1)

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN substring(telephone_number, 1, 1) <> '9'
  THEN telephone_number
ELSE substring(telephone_number, 2, LEN(telephone_number))
END
FROM Telephone
```

Comment: In your `ELSE`, the starting position should be 2, not 1. 1 is the start of the string, so the output will still include 9.

Answer (score 5):

I recently solved a similar problem with a combination of RIGHT(), LEN() & PATINDEX().  PATINDEX will return the integer 1 when it finds a 9 as the first character and 0 otherwise. This method allows all records to be returned at once without a CASE WHEN statement.

```
SELECT
    RIGHT(number, LEN(number) - PATINDEX('9%', number))
FROM Telephone
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Update Telephone set number = RIGHT(number,LEN(number)-1) WHERE number LIKE '9%';
```

Comment: To me it seems wasteful to determine the length.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE dbo.Telephone 
  SET column_name = SUBSTRING(column_name, 2, 255)
  WHERE column_name LIKE '9%';
```

Comment: I prefer the RIGHT+LEN or STUFF method, this assumes a length which is never a good idea.

Comment: @Aki you just need to use a length that the column name will never exceed - in this case it is doubtful you would ever need more than 255 characters for a phone number, but maybe you have different phone number formats that I'm unaware of. I don't like RIGHT+LEN because taking the LEN seems a wasteful and unnecessary computation to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @STR nvarchar(200) = 'TEST'
SET @STR = STUFF(@STR,1,1,'')
PRINT @STR
```

Result will be "EST"

Answer (score 0):

Stuff is a great function for this. However, using it with an update statement with a where clause is great, but what if I was doing an insert, and I needed all of the rows inserted in one pass. The below will remove the first character if it is a period, does not use the slower case statement, and converts nulls to an empty string.

```
DECLARE @Attachment varchar(6) = '.GIF',
        @Attachment2 varchar(6)

SELECT
  @Attachment2 = ISNULL(ISNULL(NULLIF(LEFT(@Attachment, 1), '.'), '') + STUFF(@Attachment, 1, 1, ''), '')

SELECT
  @Attachment2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace in select statement instead of where or update

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('_'+number,'_9',''),'_','') FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below example:

```sql
Declare @HearingTime Varchar(Max) = '09:00 AM'
Declare @FirstDigit Varchar(1)

Select @FirstDigit = SUBSTRING(@HearingTime, 1, 1)

If (@FirstDigit = '0')
Begin
    Select @HearingTime = Substring(@HearingTime, 2, LEN(@HearingTime))
End
Select @HearingTime
--9:00 AM
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**