# Update email field value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've a column `email` in my table `person`, email column contains entries like

```
sam@yahoo.com
xxxashish@gmail.com
sunny@rediff.com
xxxSomil@google.com
```

Now I want to update value of email column and remove all `xxx` from the begining of email id's. Any ideas how to achieve this?

**Example**: `xxxashish@gmail.com` should be `ashish@gmail.com`

Comment: do you always want to replace xxx, or does xxx contain values?

Comment: I want to remove `xxx` from the beginning of email id's Eg: `xxxashish@gmail.com` should be `ashish@gmail.com`

Comment: what about such email: xxxazatxxx@ya.com, should it become just azat@ya.ru or azatxxx@ya.ru?

Comment: @Rocketq: that's fine for me. I just want to remove `xxx` from begining

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

`UPDATE person
   SET email = RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - 3) 
   WHERE email LIKE 'xxx%';`

this way you wont replace `xxx` that might come in the text

so `xxxladidaxxx@gmail.com` will return `ladidaxxx@gmail.com`

Answer (score 4):

try

```
update 
person
set email = REPLACE(email,'xxx','')
where email like 'xxx%'
```

If xxx come in between email the above will replace that also.For that below code works

```
   update 
    person
    set email = RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - 3) 
    where email like 'xxx%'
```

Comment: what is the purpose of line `where email = email`?

Comment: if the e-mail adress itself contains xxx both at beginning and inbetween, this will get replaced as well.. (see my answer) `xxxladidaxxx@gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can check this also.

```
Declare @t table(email varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('sam@yahoo.com'), ('xxxashish@gmail.com' ),('sunny@rediff.com' ),('xxxSomil@google.com')

UPDATE @t
SET email = STUFF( email , 1 , 3 ,'')
WHERE email LIKE 'xxx%'

select * from @t
```

[How to remove the first character if it is a specific character in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974323/how-to-remove-the-first-character-if-it-is-a-specific-character-in-sql)

Comment: It gives wrong output when name starts with x, like `xsam@yahoo.com`, it will give output of `xsam@yahoo.com` as `m@yahoo.com`